# How to calculate buffer surface that falls within another layer's borders

Tags: qgis, buffer, area, ftools

The image below shows what two selected layers. One contains a series of borders, and the other a series of buffers.

I am trying to obtain the buffered surface within each of the borders in the other layer, preferably using ftools.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer to my own question. This involved several steps:

1. Initially, I drew buffers around the points in question and saved the resulting polygons in a new shape file.
2. Going to "vector" on the qGIS menu, I selected "geoprocessing tools" and then "intersect". Here I selected the two layers of interest and again saved the results as a new shape file. The resulting polygon contains only the area in which there is an overlap. Importantly, it also preserves the boundaries of each starting layer.
3. Opening the layer saved in the previous step, I then went to vector->geometry tools->export/add geometry columns. This once again leads to saving a shape file, but in this one the attribute table has two added columns with the area and perimeter of the overlapping sections, organised along the same rows as the starting file, which is precisely what I needed.

I hope this is useful for others!